# tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer can vals_tensor be a N-D tensor? not a single vector

Tags: tensorflow

```
keys_tensor = tf.constant(['a','b','c'])
vals_tensor = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7, 8, 9]])
input_tensor = tf.constant([['a'],['b']])
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys_tensor, vals_tensor),0)
#out = table.lookup(input_tensor)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    #print(sess.run(out))
```

Here, I want to get `a` with `[1,2,3]`, `b` with `[4,5,6]`, but error occurs with:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at lookup_table_op.cc:1060 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected shape [3] for value, got [3,3]
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected shape [3] for value, got [3,3]
     [[{{node key_value_init/LookupTableImportV2}}]]
2023-04-19 19:34:57.560865: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected shape [3] for value, got [3,3]
```